# Matrix Derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I would like to find the derivative of the quantity below w.r.t. $X:$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} \ln(|X|)$.

How could I use the following expression from: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf ?

$∂(ln(det(X)))=Tr(X^{-1}∂X)$ eq. 43

Or if could I somehow transform it in such form so I can use eq.43? I am not looking for some fancy derivation, just an expression that can be easily implemented on R/Python/Matlab.

Comment: $tr(X^{-1} \partial X)$ is pretty implementation friendly. As for the proof: Consider $f(t) = \ln(|X+t E_{i,j}|)$ and assume $X$ is diagonal and $E_{i,j} = e_ie_j^T$ is the matrix having 1 at $(i,j)$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @user251257 Yeah, i know that this expression is implementation friendly, but I am not sure if it is correct for my problem. I mean, on matrix cookbook they talk about $det(X)$ but my expression has not $det$ in there. Unless I am missing something critical here from linear algebra.

Comment: I am not sure, what you mean. Some writes $|X|$ for $\det X$.

Comment: @user251257 Holy.... Cheers, makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what the Eq. 43 expression works out to is that the derivative of $\ln(|X|)$ with respect to an element $X_{i,j}$ (that is, $\frac{\partial (\ln(|X|))}{\partial X_{i,j}}$) is just $(X^{-1})_{j,i}.$ Is that what you want to compute?